# Alias for a template struct inside another template struct

Tags: c++, templates, alias

I want to write a function type that transform a type `B` in the same type but with the same sign that another type `A`. I can achieve that using this function:

```
template <typename A, typename B, bool = std::is_signed_v<B>>
struct same_sign_as{
    using type = std::make_signed_t<A>;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct same_sign_as<A, B, false>{
    using type = std::make_unsigned_t<A>;
};
```

and then use it as `using R = same_sign_as_t<A,B>;`.

But I want my code to be readable. When I see a function simliar to `same_sign_as` I never know if it means the type `A` with the sign of `B` or the type of `B` with the sign of `A`.

As I don't want to remember this kind of things I'd like to write better something similar to

```
using R = make_type<A>::same_sign_as<B>
```

With this I'm not going to make any mistakes.

Is easy to write it:

```
template <typename A>
struct make_type{
    template <typename B>
    struct same_sign_as
    { using type = typename __same_sign_as<A, B>::type; };
};
```

where I changed the name of `same_sign_as` for `__same_sign_as` (I want this function to be an implementation detail).

To use `make_type` write:

```
using Res = typename make_type<A>::template same_sign_as<B>::type
```

and that is horrible. You can't read that!!!

Can I define an alias to achieve my goal of writing

```
using Res = make_type<A>::same_sign_as<B>
```

?

Comment: You can get rid of the first `typename` using an alias, but if `A` is a template parameter you will always need the `::template` part.

Comment: @super Actually, if you just write another `using` alias, you can avoid writing both `template` and `typename`.

Comment: Don’t use names with double underscores: they’re reserved to the implementation.

Comment: as long as `A` is a dependent name, `using Res = make_type<A>::same_sign_as<B>` must be `using Res = make_type<A>::template same_sign_as<B>`. because compiler doesn't know what `same_sign_as` is in an indeterminate context.

Comment: @cigien Pretty sure that's not possible. Feel free to prove me wrong.

Comment: @super I thought the OP is expecting to do something like this https://godbolt.org/z/15bqd1 but if the argument to `make_type` is a template parameter, then you're right, I think `template` is necessary.